# ListView and footer - how to eliminate space between them?

Tags: android, listview, footer

There's a kind of glitch between last listview's element and it's footer - it doesn't have a divider but it has a space for that . so , if I make a black background, for instance, this glitching space will be black and so on.

How can I eliminate this spacing ?

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_for_main, null);
//adding a footer:
    lvMain.addFooterView(v);
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/main_footer_tile_long"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ver_main_donate_background_tile_long"
    android:divider="@drawable/linear"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"

    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_main_list" >

</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: What if you change this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to this `android:layout_height="match_parent"`?

Comment: You should never put `wrap_content` as `android:layout_height` of a `ListView`. `wrap_content` on a ListView defies its sole purpose.

Comment: Please post your activity code

Comment: Xaver Kapeller , that doesn't help , result is the same, it has a spacing at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
footerView.setPadding(0, -3, 0, 0);
```

As 3px is the default height of the divider.

Comment: I edited the post - footerView doesn't have .setDividerHeight(0); as any View

Comment: Good point, this is a method of ListView. I have edited the answer.

Comment: this really just makes a footer disappear.  but the spacing at the bottom remains